# Is it possible to to add a part of speech tag to a spaCy tokenizer special case?

Tags: python, spacy, tokenize, pos-tagger

I have a list of compounds and other special cases that I want spaCy to recognise as tokens, such as 'according to' and 'washing machine'. I used 'add_special_case' to do this:

```
    import spacy
    from spacy.attrs import ORTH

    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

    text = "according to reports the washing machine industry is declining"

    special_case_1 = [{ORTH: 'according to'}]
    nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case('according to', special_case_1)

    special_case_2 = [{ORTH: 'washing machine'}]
    nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case('washing machine', special_case_2)

    doc = nlp(text)

    for token in doc:
    print(token, token.pos_)
```

This seems to work, but the POS tag is now proper noun, when it should be preposition (ADP) for 'according to' and NOUN for 'washing machine':

```
    according to PROPN
    reports VERB
    the DET
    washing machine PROPN
    industry NOUN
    is AUX
    declining VERB
```

Does anybody know if there is a way to assign a POS tag to a special case? (I couldn't find anything in the documentation). Or maybe there is a better way to tokenize compounds?

**Solution**

The solution was to use the AttributeRuler in spaCy https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#mappings-exceptions

```
    import spacy
    from spacy.attrs import ORTH

    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

    text = "according to reports the washing machine is more         
    popular than air conditioning because of an unknown reason"

    compounds = ['according to', 'because of', 'washing machine',         
    'air conditioning']

    for comp in compounds:
        special_case = [{ORTH: comp}]
        nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(comp, special_case)
```

This gave the following tags to the 4 compounds:

```
    according to PROPN NNP
    washing machine PROPN NNP
    air conditioning VERB VBG
    because of VERB VBZ
```

Then I used the AttributeRuler:

```
    ruler = nlp.get_pipe("attribute_ruler")

    prepositions = ['according to', 'because of']
    nouns = ['washing machine', 'air conditioning']

    for prep in prepositions:
        preposition_patterns = [[{"LOWER": prep}]]
        preposition_attrs = {"TAG": "IN", "POS": "ADP"}
        ruler.add(patterns=preposition_patterns,         
        attrs=preposition_attrs)

    for noun in nouns:
        noun_patterns = [[{"LOWER": noun}]]
        noun_attrs = {"TAG": "NN", "POS": "NOUN"}
        ruler.add(patterns=noun_patterns, attrs=noun_attrs)
```

This time the output was what I wanted:

```
    according to ADP IN
    washing machine NOUN NN
    air conditioning NOUN NN
    because of ADP IN
```

I still need to work on tokenizing the lemma of a compound noun (including the plural form). For my case, the list of compounds is small enough to manually add the plural form of each compound noun to the compound list, but doing that is probably not the best solution.

Comment: See: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#mappings-exceptions

Comment: Thank you! I got this to work using the documentation in the link, for reference, I added the code I used above

Comment: Thanks for putting your solution here. Consider submitting it in the answer space below.

Comment: Also, what you put above seems to hint that the compound nouns were tokenized into multiple tokens (e.g., "NOUN NN"). Is that true? When I add a special case that is a compound noun, it comes out as a single token. Perhaps you could add the code that shows the output you generated?